# WPF Error 40 BindingExpression path error: property not found on 'object'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm banging my head on my desk with this binding error..  I have checked several of the postings for the `BindingExpression` path error and cannot see anything that works with my situation.

Anyway, I have a custom control called `IncrementingTextBox`.  I am trying to disable it whenever the user 'checks' the `CheckBox` above it.

I have a binding on the `CheckBox` `IsChecked` property that is working fine and is firing when it is supposed to.  It is correctly setting the `UseSensorLength` property on the ConfigurationModel.

However, the binding on the `IncrementingTextBox` `IsEnabled` property is causing a `BindingExpression` path error and so doesn't update at all.

As a test, I tried in the code behind to enable and disable the control and it works just fine, but I can't seem to get the Binding to work on it.

Here is a snippet from my xaml:

```
...

DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

...
...

<CheckBox Content="Use Sensor Length" Margin="30,6,0,0" 
          IsChecked="{Binding ConfigurationModel.UseSensorLength, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<local:IncrementingTextBox x:Name="video_length_textbox" Margin="0,0,0,5" 
                           IsTextEnabled="False" 
                           IsEnabled="{Binding ConfigurationModel.DontUseSensorLength}" 
                           ValueChanged="VideoEventValueChanged"/>
```

And Here is a snippet from my ConfigurationModel:

```
public bool DontUseSensorLength
{
    get { return !UseSensorLength; }
}

public bool UseSensorLength
{
   get { return _useSensorLength; }
   set 
   { 
      _useSensorLength = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged("UseSensorLength"); 
      OnPropertyChanged("DontUseSensorLength");
   }
}
```

Here is the error message I am getting in my output window when running the app:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'ConfigurationModel' property not found on 'object'
>   ''IncrementingTextBox' (Name='video_length_textbox')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ConfigurationModel.DontUseSensorLength;
>   DataItem='IncrementingTextBox' (Name='video_length_textbox'); target
>   element is 'IncrementingTextBox' (Name='video_length_textbox'); target
>   property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')

Remember, the 'UseSensorLength' property binding is working fine, but the 'DontUseSensorLength' binding is causing the above 'BindingExpression path error'.

Comment: Can you post the error as well that you get from the Output Window?

Comment: I have added the error message text to the above posting.

Comment: You have to set the DataContext to reflect your current User Control. When you create the binding, it is looking inside `IncrementingTextBox`'s DataContext for the `ConfigurationModel.DontUseSensorLength` value. You have to use a `RelativeSource` similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11550721/1466627).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I wrote some other SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14523290/302677) recently about how to read the binding errors so they make more sense. To summarize, add line breaks to your error message on the colons and semi-colons, and read it from the bottom up.

Your error message is:

- System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :

  - BindingExpression path error: 'ConfigurationModel' property not found on 'object' ''IncrementingTextBox' (Name='video_length_textbox')'.
  - BindingExpression:Path=ConfigurationModel.DontUseSensorLength;
- DataItem='IncrementingTextBox' (Name='video_length_textbox');
- target element is 'IncrementingTextBox' (Name='video_length_textbox');
- target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')

This can be read from the bottom up as:

- The binding failing is the `IsEnabled` property of an element of type `IncrementingTextBox` (named video_length_textbox).
- The `DataItem` (`DataContext`) of the element is an object of type `IncrementingTextBox` named video_length_textbox
- The binding expression it is trying to find is `ConfigurationModel.DontUseSensorLength`
- And the problem the binding is having is that the `ConfigurationModel` property is not found on the data context object `IncrementingTextBox`

So your `DataContext` for "video_length_textbox" is set to itself, and your `IncrementingTextBox` class does not have a public property called `ConfigurationModel`

Since I don't see you setting the `DataContext` for your `IncrementingTextBox` anywhere in your XAML, check out the code for your `IncrementingTextBox` class. The most likely case is you are setting the DataContext to itself in either the Constructor

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

or the XAML

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Comment: Rachel, you are a beautiful genius!!!  And I am an idiot.  Thank you so much for the solution.  I was binding to self and didn't have a 'ConfigurationModel' property in my IncrementingTextBox class.  Again, thanks !!!  For some reason, I just can't wrap my head around binding sometimes..  I try to use it all the time, but seem to run into dumb Curtis mistakes on a regular basis.  Eventually I'll get it figured out..

Comment: @Curtis Don't worry, it gets easy once you understand how WPF works. You might be interested in reading a beginner blog post I have: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). To summarize, a WPF application has two layers: the data layer (the `DataContext`) and a UI layer. Bindings are used to pull data from the data layer into the UI layer, and the UI layer is really only meant to be a pretty user-friendly interface for the data layer. Once you learn to keep those layers separate, it becomes easy :)

Answer (score 116):

I had same problem because class of object from which I was pulling out data didn't have get; and set; on its properties.

this didn't work:

```
public string Name;
```

but this worked:

```
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Yep, it can't be a field, it has to be a property.  This was my problem exactly.

Comment: Thanks, I've been misleading by a tutorial. Has to be a property.

Comment: I had the same problem and i was missing the public accessor! Sometimes the solution is easier than it seems.

Comment: Wow I spent over 2 hours trying to figure out why and it was because I just had fields in my object instead of properties. 0_o

Comment: I stared at Rachel's answer for a good long while.  Then I read yours and *facepalm*.  Property...not field.

Comment: Just spent 3 hours on this nonsense

Comment: I had "{Binding DataContext.ListOfStuff, Mode = OneWay}" but I should have had "{Binding ListOfStuff, Mode = OneWay}" . The really bad ones are when you mis-type it by the case of a single letter. The lack of design time validation makes things like this hard to find.

Comment: He Ram.. Spent one full day on this.. :-(

Comment: Also don't forget the `public`. Everything is `private` by default, I remembered after half a day.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar experience, the ItemsSource binding on a Combobox did not work.

In my case it was a minor mistake, but a difficult one to track until I enabled trace messages.

I simply forget to turn my List into a property :(

```
// NOPE:
public List<string> Versions;
// YEP:
public List<string> Versions { get; set; }
```

Maybe this helps someone...

Comment: I guess you missed Janiiik's solution?

Answer (score 6):

```
public Window()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = this;
}
public string Name {get;}
//xaml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Properties `Name` should be `public` and `{ get; }`

Comment: I've spent couple hours of figuring out why does `Children` objects of my `Parent` node in TreeView are not displayed, and your answer helped me to realize, that I simply didn't have `get` accessor for `Children` object...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and in my case I was using `bool` instead of `Boolean`. As soon as I changed it, it's working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Few things to check

1.assign values in properties before InitializeComponent in constructor

```
 public partial class SampleClass: UserControl
{
    public SampleClass()
    {
        ScenarioHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - 350;
        InitializeComponent();           


    }

    public double ScenarioHeight  { get;set;}
```

2.if its a usercontrol make sure to add userControl as Element in the binding

```
 <ScrollViewer Name="sv" Height="{Binding Path=ScenarioHeight, ElementName=ucSampleClass}" >
```

Answer (score 2):

This error may also occur when you were previously trying to bind inaccessible or non-existing Enumerable instance using XAML property `<ItemsSource>`

When you correct the `ItemsSource` with the correct value XAML doesn't automatically reilitialize the collection of items.

So when I was using the `ListBox` UI - list representation I faced this in the properties:

[image]

Deleting all the items in collection and correcting `ItemSource` value was the key.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at Shahid's answer, I noticed in my case that I had set the `DataContext` to a reference in the `Loaded` event instead of in the constructor. Moving it to the constructor fixed the issue.

Comment: Makes sense. Constructor runs before Loading and resolving Bindings

Answer (score -2):

I got this error and my case was as simple as setting the String I was binding to from private to public.

Careless mistake writing my backing field.

Comment: This statement is probably more of a comment than an answer, because it doesn't provide any specific resolution to the poster's question.